# Create a child thread that is independent of parent in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, process

I am working in a C++ DLL module where I need to perform a task for every X min independently. I tried to create a thread for the task but my main program which creates threads will also keep waiting for the child thread(s) to complete.

Could someone please help me how to create a separate process (Please provide sample code if possible) independent of main program and do the Task?
The process should take a function and run the code present in function for every X min.

**EDIT**:

```
void test(void *param)
{
    cout << "In thread function" << endl;
    Sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second
    cout << "Thread function ends" << endl;
    _endthread();
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    cout << "Starting thread" << endl;
    cout << (hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthread(test,0,NULL));
    WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
    cout << "Main ends" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CreateThread()` and `beginthreadex()` do not wait for the thread to complete. They return a handle that can be used to wait for the thread complete.

Comment: Show your code first - the code which start new thread for example.

Comment: Usually creating threads won't imply that the creating thread needs to wait for them on completion (that's what threading is all about!!). If you mean your main process shouldn't wait for these on exiting you need to create a child process, that runs independently (-> fork/exec). You really should show some code you have and where you have problems with it.

Comment: @kuperspb: lets take the example i pasted i dont want main to wait for thread but thread should still run. Could you please tell how should i code in c++?

Comment: Why the downvote?? What's wrong with this question?

Comment: Main thread is waiting because you asked it to with "WaitForSingleObject". You want to create a "detached thread". I have a threading tutorial here that goes over the basics: http://oroboro.com/portable-threads-and-mutexes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WaitForSingleObject()` will block main until the thread completes. If you want to run some stuff periodically from the thread function `test()` you'll need to put a loop there. Best with some condition to trigger ending the thread function from `main()` when exiting. You shouldn't call `WaitForSingleObject()` before you want to exit the `main()` method. Thus you'll have the `test()` method running asynchonously.

```
bool endThread = false;
void test(void *param)
{
    cout << "In thread function" << endl;
    while(!endThread)
    {
        Sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second
    }

    cout << "Thread function ends" << endl;
    _endthread();
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    cout << "Starting thread" << endl;
    cout << (hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthread(test,0,NULL));

    // Do any other stuff without waiting for the thread to end
    // ...

    endThread = true;
    WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
    cout << "Main ends" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you might need to synchronize access to the `endThread` variable properly using a mutex or similar, the sample should just show the principle.

**UPDATE:**

In case you want to exit `main()` before the thread ends, you cannot use threads at all.

You'll need to create an independent child process as I had mentioned in my 1st comment. Lookup for the `fork()` and `exec()` functions to do this (there might be specific WinAPI methods for these also, I don't know about).

Comment: I actaully need the child thread independent of main. I understood that calling WaitForSingleObject makes main to wait until child completes. But if i dont call it, my child is getting killed as main is exiting. I want child to execute even if main quits.